# Unable to render date from model template

Tags: groovy, freemarker

I'm working on a Grails project with Freemarker and am having trouble rendering a date from the data model. I start put placing a date into the model

```
def dataModel = [:]
def dataDate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd","2015-08-20")
dataModel.put("someDate",dataDate)
```

I then loop through the dataModel to verify the data types

```
dataModel.each { name, value ->
    println "${name} : ${value} (Value is type: ${value.getClass()})"
}
```

For this my output is: `someDate : Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 CDT 2015 (Value is type: class java.util.Date)`

Next I set up my confiuration and try to process the template

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_22)
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")
def ftlTemplate = new Template("name", new StringReader("${someDate}"), cfg)
Writer out = new StringWriter()
ftlTemplate.process(dataModel, out)
output = out.toString()
```

At this point I receive the following error

```
ERROR freemarker.runtime  - Error executing FreeMarker template
Message: Can't convert the date-like value to string because it isn't known if it's a date (no time part), time or date-time value.
The blamed expression:
==> someDate  [in template "name" at line 1, column 3]
```

I've found a Freemarker engine online here: http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/ and if I run the same datamodel and template through that the ouput I receive is: `Aug 20, 2015`

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?  I would like to render the output like that online engine does.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is (as the error message states) is that it's technically impossible to decide in general, if a `java.util.Date` stands for a date-only, date-time or time-only value. This is a technical fact that's outside FreeMarker. FreeMarker offers these ways to handle this problem:

- Use `?date`, `?time` and `?datetime` operators to give FreeMarker a hint in the template. See: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_date_datetype
- Use `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.sql.Timestamp`, where there's no such ambiguity. (Beware with `Timestamp`'s funny fraction second handling though.)
- Wrap the values manually into `TemplateDateModel`, where you can specify which kind of value it is. Then drop the `TemplateDateModel` into the data-model.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
new StringReader("${someDate}")
```

To

```
new StringReader('${someDate}')
```

The double quotes are probably causing double tempering

Comment: Thanks Tim, but that did not solve my issue.  In reality my code get the template from another variable so it's more like this StringReader(myVar)  BUT I did change it to what you said specifically and forwent the variable and it still produced the same error.

Answer (score -1):

**hi,look! you can try like these:**

```
<td name="">${value.startTime?string('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')}</td>
```

**the you can replace value.startTime with the target varibale which is date or timestamp type**