# Groovy template engine with parameters matching a Java class name

Tags: groovy

I'm sure this is a simple one...

We use the Groovy template engine to format XML documents into human-readable form. The code scans the XML and creates a map with an entry for each item in the XML, and then this is passed to the Groovy template engine.

Problem occurs when the XML contains an attribute that matches a class name -
 something like this: `<Date>some date</Date>`. If the template file specifies `Date is $Date` (for example), instead of the actual date string, we're getting `class java.util.Date`. We've tried variations on `$Date` like `${Date}` and `${Date.toString()}`, etc with no luck.

We think the issue is that Groovy confuses Date the input variable, and the java.util.Date class, but I'm sure there's some sort of syntax that will make this work properly. Since we feed arbitrary user-defined XML through this, we really can't control things like the attribute names in the XML.

Here's a few lines of code to replicate the problem:

```
def map = [:]
map.putAt("Date",  new Date())  // Fails
map.putAt("Date2", new Date())  // Works
def tf = new File("Test.template")
def gte = new GStringTemplateEngine()
def tpl = gte.createTemplate(tf).make(map.withDefault{null})
println tpl.toString()
```

The "Test.template" file contains:

```
Date is ${Date.toString()}.
Date is ${Date2.toString()}.
```

The output we get is:

```
Date is class java.util.Date.
Date is Tue Jun 06 20:22:16 EDT 2017.
```

Comment: I believe that the templating engine is case sensitive right? You could try to uppercase the tag value before putting it in your map? Otherwise, make it so that you access the childs of another object. Something like myThing.Date.toString. It would ensure that you have the right date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to render date from model template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123950/unable-to-render-date-from-model-template)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems groovy takes class `Date` prior to binding variable named `Date`

So, why not to pass all xml attributes as one binding variable:

```
def map = [:]
map.putAt("Date",  new Date())  // Fails
map.putAt("Date2", new Date())  // Works
def gte = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def tpl = gte.createTemplate('''
Date  :: ${ctx.Date.toString()}
Date2 :: ${ctx.Date2.toString()}
''').make( [ctx:map].withDefault{null})

println tpl.toString()
```

also it's possible to access variables through this kind of accessor `delegate.'My strange Variable'`:

```
def map = [:]
map.putAt("Date",  new Date())  // Fails
map.putAt("Date2", new Date())  // Works
def gte = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def tpl = gte.createTemplate('''
Date  :: ${delegate.'Date'.toString()}
Date2 :: ${Date2.toString()}
''').make( map.withDefault{null})

println tpl.toString()
```

Comment: There are several hundred existing templates, so your suggestion would require changing them, which we want to avoid.

Comment: you could pass variables in old style and in new style. and for the cases like you mentioned use a new style accessor, or for all new templates use new accessor. so, you can support both. btw, the worth case will be when your variable will be named like a keyword `in`, `if`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, just in case someone else has a similar problem.

We found that the Groovy "getVariable()" method is a solution that works for us. The getVariable() method returns the value of any variable, and it's exposed inside the template engine. Changing the template to in my example above to:

```
Date is ${getVariable("Date")}
```

Solved the problem for us.